# I can not create PostgreSQL database via prompt with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql

Hello Guys I'm trying to study Ruby On Rails but I can not continue reading a book written by
Brazilian author.

I was going step by step (A, B, C, D, see below) and PROPERLY INSTALLED POSTGRESQL

**A) I installed Ruby correctly.**

```
C:\rails>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]
```

**B) I installed Gems correctly.**

```
C:\rails>gem -v
2.1.11
```

**C) I installed all the gems RAILS correctly.**

```
***************************** GEM INSTALADADAS ***********

gem install rubygems-update-1.3.1.gem

gem install rake-0.8.4.gem

gem install activesupport-1.4.4.gem


gem install activesupport-2.3.2.gem 

gem install activerecord-1.15.6.gem  

gem install activerecord-2.3.2.gem

gem install actionpack-1.13.6.gem REM ***

gem install actionpack-2.3.2.gem 

gem install actionmailer-2.3.2.gem

gem install actionwebservice-1.2.6.gem

gem install activeresource-2.3.2.gem  

gem install rails-2.3.2.gem 

gem install postgres-pr-0.6.1.gem
```

**D) Rails installed correctly.**

```
C:\rails>rails -v
Rails 2.3.2
```

Getting run the following command

```
cd projetos 

rails --database postgresql projeto01
```

Template created the perfect site.

When running the command

```
cd\projetos\projeto01 
rake db:create
```

The following errors have appeared:

ERROR 1

```
C:\Projetos\projeto01>rake db:create
uninitialized constant PostgresPR::Connection::UNIXSocket
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependen
cies.rb:105:in `rescue in const_missing'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependen
cies.rb:94:in `const_missing'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb
:167:in `establish_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb
:51:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-comp
at.rb:23:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-comp
at.rb:23:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:916:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:916:in `connect'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:210:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `block in checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:70:in `res
cue in create_database'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:35:in `cre
ate_database'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:31:in `blo
ck (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in e
xecute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in i
nvoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_wit
h_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `inv
oke_task'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `blo
ck (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `eac
h'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `blo
ck in top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run
_with_threads'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top
_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `bloc
k in run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `sta
ndard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'

C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"UTF-8", "dat
abase"=>"projeto01_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"exercicio_livro", "pass
word"=>"rails"}

C:\Projetos\projeto01>rake db:create
uninitialized constant PostgresPR::Connection::UNIXSocket
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependen
cies.rb:105:in `rescue in const_missing'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependen
cies.rb:94:in `const_missing'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb
:167:in `establish_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb
:51:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-comp
at.rb:23:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.1/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-comp
at.rb:23:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:916:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:916:in `connect'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:210:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `block in checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:70:in `res
cue in create_database'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:35:in `cre
ate_database'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:31:in `blo
ck (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in e
xecute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in i
nvoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_wit
h_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `inv
oke_task'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `blo
ck (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `eac
h'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `blo
ck in top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run
_with_threads'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top
_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `bloc
k in run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `sta
ndard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'

C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"UTF-8", "dat
abase"=>"projeto01_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"exercicio_livro", "pass
word"=>"rails"}

C:\Projetos\projeto01
```

ERROR 2

```
C:\Projetos\projeto01> ruby script/server
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `requ
ire': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.r
b:55:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I would recommend getting a newer book, you should be working with Rails4 (not Rails2) if you're just starting.

Answer (score 1):

You have `postgres-pr` gem in your Gemfile, as far as I know it is no longer supported by Rails, use `pg` gem instead.

Comment: as well as install the correct gem ?

In the book I'm reading tells just install postgres-pr-0.6.1.gem

What's for RAILS 2.3.2

Comment: Replace postgres-pr with pg in your gemfile, run Bundle and you should be fine. Rails 2.3.2? This must be a really old book, it's bit outdated now.